# C# asynchronous calling block the window

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I use a `informationWindow(iw)` to show some command results. The `iw` is hiding behind the main window and the main window is disabled untill an asynchronous call completes. Since it's an asynchronous call, I have no idea why the window hides.

```
       LKProcess.AsyncDelegate caller = new LKProcess.AsyncDelegate(LKProcess.RunCommands);
    IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(cmds, null, null);
    //result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();


    iw.Show();
    iw.Topmost=true;

    var resultList = caller.EndInvoke(result);
    string combindedString = string.Join(",", resultList);       
    iw.tbkMessageBox.Inlines.Add(combindedString );
```

**Update:**
I move the iw.Show() out of asynchronous calling, but nothing changed, is the delegate method (CMD process in my case) blocking the main window?

```
iw.Show();
iw.Topmost=true;
LKProcess.AsyncDelegate caller = new LKProcess.AsyncDelegate(LKProcess.RunCommands);
IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(cmds, null, null);        
        var resultList = caller.EndInvoke(result);
        string combindedString = string.Join(",", resultList);
```

**Update**
I did a further test, now my AsyncDelegate is sth like:

```
public static class LKProcess
    {
        public delegate IEnumerable<string> AsyncDelegate(params string[] commands);
        public static IEnumerable<string> RunCommands(params string[] commands)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            var result = new List<string>();
            Return result;
        }
    }
```

And my main looks like:

```
iw.Show();
            iw.Topmost = true;
            iw.tbkMessageBox.Inlines.Add("IT's Start");
            LKProcess.AsyncDelegate caller = new LKProcess.AsyncDelegate(LKProcess.RunCommands);
var resultList = caller.EndInvoke(result);
```

Now the iw shows, flash across, and then hide while asynchronous calling get invoked, 5s later, iw shows on top. Say "IT's Start". The calling is NOT blocing the main window, but take over the stage...

Comment: *Since it's an asynchronous calling* Because you `WaitOne` on it.

Comment: sorry, should comment that line, but nothing changed, the window is still  blocked

Comment: [EndInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/2e08f6yc.aspx) blocks the thread until the asynchronous operation is completed. You should instead assign a delegate to be called when the operation is complete (see further down the linked page "Executing a Callback Method When an Asynchronous Call Completes") EDIT: Also, this will likely be on a background thread so you may not be able to directly update `iw.tbkMessageBox`; you may need to promote that operation back to the main thread (or perhaps you should use the `async/await` syntax?)

Comment: I moved the iw.show() out of the asynchronous calling, the iw window still hide behind. Is possiable the CMD process (delegate method) block this window?